# Neo4j Cypher select where exists query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph structure like this:[image]

I need to select all `ContentItem` nodes they have any connections with the other nodes.

I am also passing in a list of ids for each of the nodes for filtering purposes.  i.e. I pass in a list of the neo4j ids for the items I wish to INCLUDE in the search.  Any `ContentItem` that is related to any of the other nodes which have an id passed in should return.

I've tried with a UNION as this felt like the simplest way, but I'm not sure that it's correct.

```
MATCH (n:ContentItem) WHERE id(n) IN $neoIds
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:IN]->(pt:PulseTopic) WHERE id(pt) IN $pulseTopics RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:IN]->(pst:SubPulseTopic) WHERE id(pst) IN $subPulseTopics RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:FROM]->(s:Supplier) WHERE id(s) IN $suppliers RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:USED_FOR]->(ua:UseArea) WHERE id(ua) IN $useAreas RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:IN]->(blt:BLTopic) WHERE id(blt) IN $blTopics RETURN n
```

Firstly when I reference the record in python I get an error:

```
for r in tx.run(cypherStep2, paramsStep2):
    d = r['n']['id']
```

...gives:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

I'm not sure why that would be.  If I just do `MATCH (n:ContentItem) WHERE id(n) IN $neoIds RETURN n` I don't get this error, so I'm thinking this is something to do with the `UNION`.

And secondly, I am wondering if this will actually filter ContentItem on `$neoIds` passed in or whether `OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)` means ANY `ContentItem` in the `UNION`.

What is the best way to do a query like this, please?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

This query uses the new [existential subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#existential-subqueries) feature to return every `ContentItem` node whose native ID is in `$neoIds` and has any of the desired relationships:

```
MATCH (n:ContentItem)
WHERE
  ID(n) IN $neoIds AND (
    EXISTS {
      MATCH (n)-[:IN]->(pt:PulseTopic)
      WHERE pt.id IN $pulseTopics}
    OR EXISTS {
      MATCH (n)-[:IN]->(pst:SubPulseTopic)
      WHERE pst.id IN $subPulseTopics}
    OR EXISTS {
      MATCH (n)-[:FROM]->(s:Supplier)
      WHERE s.id IN $suppliers}
    OR EXISTS {
      MATCH (n)-[:USED_FOR]->(ua:UseArea)
      WHERE ua.id IN $useAreas}
    OR EXISTS {
      MATCH (n)-[:IN]->(blt:BLTopic)
      WHERE blt.id IN $blTopics
    }
  )
RETURN n
```

This should be much more efficient than combining the results of multiple `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses, since the latter would continue to search for (and hold in memory) all possible relationship matches even when one had already been found for a particular `n` node.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  However I also need to specify the Neo4j Ids for each of the other node types.  e.g.  $pulseTopics (above).  Also there may be other relationships added to the ContentItem, so I wouldn't want to literally select where there is any relationship.  It would need to be relationships to those specific node types.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll check that out and get back to you.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I sorted it.  Firstly I actually had a mistake in there as it was the n.id value rather than the id(n) that was being passed in.

Secondly, for some unknown reason, I was getting one None result.  So I am just filtering that out in python now.

Thirdly, it seems that I need to put the `id(n) IN $neoIds` into each union query.

This doesn't seem like the best solution, but it works.  If you have any suggestions for improvements I'd be interested.  Here is the code:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:IN]->(pt:PulseTopic) WHERE pt.id IN $pulseTopics AND id(n) IN $neoIds RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:IN]->(pst:SubPulseTopic) WHERE pst.id IN $subPulseTopics AND id(n) IN $neoIds RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:FROM]->(s:Supplier) WHERE s.id IN $suppliers AND id(n) IN $neoIds RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:USED_FOR]->(ua:UseArea) WHERE ua.id IN $useAreas AND id(n) IN $neoIds RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:ContentItem)-[:IN]->(blt:BLTopic) WHERE blt.id IN $blTopics AND id(n) IN $neoIds RETURN n
```